# Display missing when layout changed to landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Scroll View as the main and inside it a couple of relative layouts and nested table layout and relative layout , when i flip the phone to landscape mode , the button i have at the end of the activity are not getting displayed. Is there a suitable way, i tried couple , it ain't working. Here is the XML code,

---

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:fadeScrollbars="false" > 

  <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/rel"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/apt"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingBottom="10dp"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:paddingRight="10dp"
          android:paddingTop="10dp" >

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/logoutxml"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:onClick="onClick"
              android:paddingRight="10dp"
              android:src="@drawable/home" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/screenheading"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:text="Create Task"
              android:textSize="18dip"
              android:textStyle="bold" />
      </RelativeLayout>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/msg"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@id/apt"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textSize="18dp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/footer"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
          android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
          android:text="All rights reserved © 2012-13.Powered by Dewhive"
          android:textSize="13sp" />


         <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rlo"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_below="@id/apt"   
           android:layout_above="@id/footer"
          >


      <TableLayout
          android:id="@+id/tb"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"         
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dip" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/id1"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:text="Assignees:"
                  android:textColor="#707070"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/asgnames"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />
          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dip" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/id2"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:text="Patner Name:"
                  android:textColor="#707070"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/patnernames"
                  android:layout_width="200dip"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:maxLines="4"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />
          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dip" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/id3"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:text="Task Id:"
                  android:textColor="#707070"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/taskid"
                  android:layout_width="200dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:maxLines="3"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />
          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dip" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/id4"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:text="Deadline Date:"
                  android:textColor="#707070"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/dldate"
                  android:layout_width="200dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:maxLines="3"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />
          </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rl11"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@id/tb"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="10dip"
           >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/id5"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
              android:gravity="left"
              android:text="Description:"
              android:textColor="#707070"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/descp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/id5"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
              android:gravity="left"
              android:maxLines="10"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/save"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
              android:layout_below="@id/descp"
              android:text="Save"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
              android:padding="2dip"/>

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/assign"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/save"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
              android:padding="2dip"
              android:text="Assign"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
               />

      </RelativeLayout>

      </RelativeLayout>

      <!--
         <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:id="@+id/bll"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:layout_below="@id/rl11"            
              >       

        <Button android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
        >
        </Button>

         <Button android:text="Assign"
        android:id="@+id/assign"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" >
        </Button>         

        </RelativeLayout>   
      -->


  </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where is the xml layout?

Comment: I can't examine your code because I see lot of it, and I don't see any ScrollView, try to put everything inside a scrollview

Comment: i have edited and posted the whole layout code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one and better to use linear layouts wherever you can

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/apt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoutxml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/screenheading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Create Task"
                android:textSize="18dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/id1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Assignees:"
                        android:textColor="#707070"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/asgnames"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/id2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Patner Name:"
                        android:textColor="#707070"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/patnernames"
                        android:layout_width="200dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:maxLines="4"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/id3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Task Id:"
                        android:textColor="#707070"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/taskid"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/id4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Deadline Date:"
                        android:textColor="#707070"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dldate"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/tb"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Description:"
                    android:textColor="#707070"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/id5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:maxLines="10"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/descp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/assign"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:text="Assign"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="AGDHAGDJAGDJABD"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="All rights reserved © 2012-13.Powered by Dewhive"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Hope it will help.Let me know.

Comment: @sanj Please change image res .

Comment: there is a lot of space between the buttons and the footer ,though no specific space value is mentioned rest is working fine, thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can specify different layouts for portrait and landscape orientations.

To do that, create two xml layouts optimized for each orientation: yourlayout_port.xml and yourlayout_land.xml.

You just have to put it under separate folders with the appropriate name depending on orientation, the device will automatically select the right one for its screen orientation.

Inside res folder create two folders named layout_land and layout_port. Place each xml layout in its matching folder.

You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)